# Remote control for mythtv?

Tags: linux, remote-control, media-center, mythtv

Can anybody reccommend a good remote control to buy to use with mythtv?

Answer (score 2):

The remote controls which come with the Hauppauge TV cards are generally quite good and work natively with kernel 2.2 onwards.

Comment: can you buy these separately from the cards?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use the [PS3](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Sony_PS3_BD_Remote) media remote. It came with my ps3 and works perfectly.

Comment: are you running mythtv on yor ps3?

Comment: No, but the remote for the ps3 is a bluetooth remote that works great.

Answer (score 1):

I user the [Streamzap USB remote](http://www.streamzap.com/) and the Android app [Mythmote](http://code.google.com/p/mythmote/).